# Adding new version to CoreData

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have a coredata model with 2 entities, one entity has a relationship with the other,(DataSet---(To many)-->DataPoints). Originally I had this relationship to have an inverse but I ended up not needing it. I knew that if I just changed it that people would have to reinstall the app, deleting all their data. So I looked up how to change it but still allow the old model to be compatible.

I followed these steps I found on SO:

1. Select the *.xcdatamodelId
2. Select Editor > Add Model Version
3. Provide a version name based on the previous model
4. Make sure you select the new version you just created
5. Give it a new identifier (in the file selector)
6. Make your changes
7. Select the *.xcdatamodelId and change the Model Version (in the file
   selector)

I also selected the model and changed "Model Version" to "*v2"

But when I run the app on a device with the old model, as soon as it trys to create data I get the error:

> Unresolved error Error Domain=YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN Code=9999 "Failed to
>   initialize the application's saved data"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize the
>   application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c06402d0 {Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The managed object model
>   version used to open the persistent store is incompatible with the one
>   that was used to create the persistent store."

I'm not sure if I missed something or I did something wrong. The only thing I changed was the relationship no longer has an inverse which isn't even used in the code. The way I understood it from my readings was if the most up to date model was not on the device it would look for a compatible model.

Comment: Are you certain lightweight migration is compatible with your changes? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html. You don't specify the options you're passing in initializing your persistence store coordinator.

Comment: @particleman It does not explicitly state whether or not changing a relationship from having and inverse to not having one is allowed in lightweight migration. I am not sure what you are saying in the second part.

Comment: Read the section `Request Automatic Migration Using an Options Dictionary` from the link above that covers asking for a lightweight migration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you setup your persistent store coordinator make sure you specify that you want it to automatically migrate your data if applicable in the options dictionary that is passed when setting it up.

Something like this:

```
    do {
        try self?.psc?.addPersistentStore(
                       ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, 
            configurationName: nil, 
                           at: url, 
                      options: [
                             NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
                             NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true
                        ])
        print("Core Data Store setup")
    } catch {
        print("Error migrating store: \(error)")
    }
```

Another option if you're building for iOS 10+ is to make use of NSPersistentContainer that manages the context, model and persistent store coordinator for you.

(I haven't tried migrations with NSPersistentContainer yet but thought I'd make you aware of them in case it simplifies things for you).

Here's a sample core data stack using NSPersistentContainer instead of the older style with persistent store coordinator, etc:

```
import CoreData

class CoreDataStack {

    // added in case you want to initialize the persistent container with a specific managed
    // object model via
    // let container = NSPersistentContainer.init(name: DataModel, managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel())
    internal func managedObjectModel() -> NSManagedObjectModel {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: AppDelegate.self)
        guard let url = bundle.url(forResource: "DataModel", withExtension: "momd") else {
            fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
        }
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(url)")
        }

        return mom
    }

    internal lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { [weak self](storeDescription, error) in

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            if let error = error {
                print("CoreData:  error \(error), \(String(describing: error._userInfo))")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    func performUITask(_ block: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void) {
        persistentContainer.viewContext.perform {
            block(self.persistentContainer.viewContext)
        }
    }

    func performBackgroundTask(_ block: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void) {
        persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask(block)
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("CoreData: Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will give this a shot

Comment: adding the following works for me

options: [
                             NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
                             NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true
                        ])